# Adobe Reader XI - How can I adjust / fine-tune the horizontal and vertical alignment for printing?

Tags: windows-7, printing, adobe-reader

- Win 7 64 bit
- Adobe Reader XI (11.0.09 to be exact)

When printing, I can choose between the following options concerning the alignment:

- Automatic upright/landscape orientation
- Upright
- Landscape

**Where are the options to specify whether the content should be centered horizontally and/or vertically? Are they gone for good?**

The thing is, AR now decides on its own, i.e. without any opportunity to intervene, how to print the content (landscape or upright) automatically. So if one needs something printed centered by both measures on an upright oriented sheet and AR decides to put it all in landscape mode, well, good luck. I just experienced this problem and this is what this topic is about.

Note: first best hit on Google, [i.e. this entry](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1177185), also did not help.

### Picture of options

[image]

Comment: So, you can't see the Page Scaling pop-up menu, just above the alignment options that you say? Can you please, post a screenshot?

Comment: @Santeador I can see that. However that section is about, as you said, the scale of the printout. Edited the op.

Comment: sorry but I don't speak german, but guess I was thinking about "Anpassen". I'm trying to figure out your problem... Have you got a PDF file with "something" that isn't in the center of the document and you need it centered?

Comment: @Santeador Sorry about the German bit. I thought the options were equal to your version of the AR. The "Anpassen" results in the content being scaled to the paper size. The thing is, AR now decides on its own, i.e. without any opportunity to intervene, how to print the content (landscape or upright) automatically. So if you need something printed centered by both measures on an upright oriented sheet and AR decides to put it all in landscape mode, well, good luck. This is what this topic is about.